# How can I connect to my SSH on DigitalOcean droplet? permission denied. (git bash Windows)

Tags: ssh, git, openssh, ssh-keys, windows-shell

How can I connect to my droplet in DigitalOcean using the openssh to be able to install my SSL Certificate, I've already added my SSH key to the droplet and my fingerprint is there, but each time I try to connect to the user using `ssh root@(IP)` I get this Error

`The authenticity of host 'IP (IP)' can't be established. ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:Uh6argd...(the rest of fingerprint). This key is not known by any other names Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes Warning: Permanently added '46.(IP)' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts. root@46.(IP): Permission denied (publickey).`

I've tried using this `pbcopy < ~/c/Users/ibrah/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` command, tried deleting the keys and generating them again, made sure that the key is registered.

I am new in this field and I am willing to learn, but this issue has taken a long time from me and I need to get it done, wish someone could assist and explain what to do exactly.

Comment: try `ssh -vvv root@xxx` and post it output.

Comment: @test92995 
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/ibrah/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/ibrah/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "xxx" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup xxx:22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxx: Name or service not known

Comment: oh sry, i mean `ssh -vvv root@$your_server_ip_address`. and you can post text by edit your question.